# Python post requests with multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, http, request, http-post

I'm having trouble making multiprocessing HTTP requests.

I'm  seeing two problems, one of them is below and the other is my tentative to increase the requests per second (see full code)

```
Exception in thread Thread-75:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "requests.py", line 189, in doWork
    doSomethingWithResult(response)
  File "requests.py", line 206, in doSomethingWithResult
    msisdn, mno_code = response
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Even when the script continue working, i can't get more than 100 TPS, even increasing the number of queues and concurrent proccess.

What is the best way to make post requests with variables? Follows what I've been trying to so far:

```
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
import logging

from urlparse import urlparse
from threading import Thread
import httplib, sys
from Queue import Queue
import json

mno_list = {
    101: 'TELECALL - Fixo',
    102: 'Life Telecom - Fixo',
    104: 'BaydeNET - Fixo',
    105: 'T.P.A - Fixo',
    106: 'America NET - Fixo',
    108: 'Global OSI - Fixo',
    109: 'MAHA-TEL TELECOM - Fixo',

}

logHandler = TimedRotatingFileHandler('lista_msisdn.txt', when="midnight")
logFormatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
logHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)

logger = logging.getLogger('time_rotate_logger')
logger.addHandler(logHandler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


concurrent = 1000

def doWork():
    while True:
        url = 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        msisdn = q.get()

        response = getStatus(url, msisdn)

        doSomethingWithResult(response)
        q.task_done()

def getStatus(url, msisdn):
    try:
        url = urlparse(url)
        payload = "msisdns=%s" % msisdn
        conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(url.netloc)
        conn.request("POST", "/check/", payload)
        res = conn.getresponse()
        response = json.loads(res.read())
        return (msisdn, response['carrierId'])
    except:
        return "error"

def doSomethingWithResult(response):
    msisdn, mno_code = response
    mno_name = mno_list.get(mno_code, 'NOK:%s' % mno_code)

    logger.debug('%s,%s' % (msisdn, mno_name))

q = Queue(concurrent * 2)
for i in range(concurrent):
    t = Thread(target=doWork)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
try:
    for msisdn in open('msisdn.txt'):
        q.put(msisdn.strip())
    q.join()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: The ValueError most probably comes from when something goes wrong in `getStatus()`, because then you are effectively doing the assignment `msisdn, mno_code = "error"`, which doesn't work (try it!). What's the use of `except: return "error"` anyway? That's just hiding useful information (the actual cause of the exception), while returning a useless value (which even causes trouble).

Comment: As for the TPS rate: have you considered bandwidth and remote response time as limiting factors? Is multithreading even helping, eg. is using two threads faster than a single one?